# SQL select in AS in inner join

Tags: sql

I have this kind of query, from that i want to select by category such as
Region in ('CENTRAL','EASTERN') as A1
and Region in ('NORTHERN','SOUTHERN') as A2

How to add this in my query?

```
SELECT
  locinvaisle.Region AS Region,
  sum(sales_data.QUANTITY/1000) AS UnitMT
FROM
  sales_data
  INNER JOIN locinvaisle ON locinvaisle.Location = sales_data.LOCATION
WHERE
 sales_data.unit = 'KG'
 and
 sales_data.CUSTOMERACCOUNT not in ('CT1008','CT1009')
 group by locinvaisle.Region
```

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `IF` or `CASE` if your database is common database such as  `mysql`,`oracle`,`mssql`:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN locinvaisle.Region = 'CENTRAL' OR locinvaisle.Region = 'EASTERN' THEN 'A1'
  CASE WHEN locinvaisle.Region = 'NORTHERN' OR locinvaisle.Region = 'SOUTHERN' THEN 'A2'
  ELSE 'Default'
  END
    AS Region,
  sum(sales_data.QUANTITY/1000) AS UnitMT
FROM
  sales_data
  INNER JOIN locinvaisle ON locinvaisle.Location = sales_data.LOCATION
WHERE
 sales_data.unit = 'KG'
 and
 sales_data.CUSTOMERACCOUNT not in ('CT1008','CT1009')
 group by Region
```

Comment: Edited: sorry i want to SELECT as A1

Comment: @AmirulFahmi can you explain more? I do not understand what you want now,is A1 a column? do you want to two column called A1 and A2?

Comment: Yes. i want to select the values in 'locinvaisle.Region' by category

Comment: @jarlh it's typo

Comment: `IF` is not part of the SQL language, but `CASE` is

Comment: You can simplify the case expression to `when locinvaisle.Region IN ('CENTRAL', 'EASTER') then ...`